# dominating function for $(1-\frac{x^2}n)^n(1+\sqrt{nx})$ in the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Compute the following limit:
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}}\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\Bigr)^{n}(1+\sqrt{n}x)dx$
>
> Hint: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\pi$

so I have a sequence $f_{n}(x)=\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\Bigr)^{n}(1+\sqrt{n}x)$ and I have to find $g\in L^{1}$ s.t $|f_{n}(x)|\le g$

it is known that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\Bigr)^{n}=e^{-x^{2}}$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\sqrt{n}x)=\infty$
how to bound this sequence above?

Comment: I'm a little confused -- your integrand is undefined on $x\in[-\sqrt{n},0)$ because of the $\sqrt{nx}$ term. Should there be an absolute value, perhaps?

In any of these cases, you can't use Dominated Convergence here -- the pointwise limit of the function is $\infty$.

Comment: there is not absolute value in the formulation of this problem. I have made a small edit, where $x$ is not under the square root.

Comment: my teacher's solution : by symmetry $\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n}x\Bigl(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\Bigr)^{n}dx=0$ and by the hint and the DCT the limit equals $\pi$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot apply the dominated convergence theorem, since the integrands aren't dominated by an integrable function.

The trick is to split the integral,

$$\int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n(1 + \sqrt{n} x)\,dx = \int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n\,dx + \sqrt{n}\int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^nx\,dx.$$

You can apply the dominated convergence theorem to the first, and the second integral is $0$ since the integrand is odd, and the interval symmetric about $0$.

Comment: The OP said this in a comment .

Comment: so i don't know why he is asking the question .

His teacher answered it before .

Comment: A full 13 seconds before I posted my answer. I didn't see the point in deleting it then. Given that the answer by the teacher was known, however, I don't understand the reason for the question either.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nice to see a comment on a solution anyway. Thanks for the help

Comment: @what'sup: If I had fully understood his 1 line solution I would have not posted it here.

Comment: @HeidiE Are things completely clear now, or are there any points I should further elaborate on?

Comment: OK , Hope you understand it now 

(+1) for you Daniel!

Comment: @DanielFischer: Everything is much clearer now. I have rated your answer. Thanks again.